# Ceiling light problem: one side too dark

Tags: materials, lighting

I´ve built a scene of a hallway where I cant seem to find out why the inside of the ceiling is too dark. Tried everything from normals, different lights, strengths, etc. Only thing working is increasing the emission, but I dont want the ceiling to emitt.

The attached file here is of only the hallway, since the original file is huge... but the problem is the same. Ceiling looks white and bright on the top/outside, but dark inside the hallway...

Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Since you are using EEVEE, you can do one of two things - bake indirect lighting, or point a light at it. The second one is the easier of the two. Select one of your ceiling (area) lights, duplicate it (shift+d), then rotate it 180 degrees on a sensible axis (Y in the long hall, for example). Do this for all your lights as needed.

Comment: Thank you. That works. Only remaining "problem" is that the Area light set up in the example file is only casting light on a small part of the hallway - even though it is set along the entire hallway. I tried changing the Area light shape to rectangle and draging it out along the Y-axis until lighting looks even spread - and then bumping up the strength to  700 000 W. Then it looks alright. But doesn´t that seems unreasonably high !?

Comment: Generally, yes. But it can depend on a lot of things. Area lights get "dimmer" the larger they are (same wattage spread out over a large area = less brightness per section). This of course changes based on the size of your objects, the distance to the lights, etc... Just remember that you're using eevee, which doesn't bounce light like cycles - everything is "fakery". If you want lighting more akin to cycles (while still using eevee), I would suggest baking the lighting by using an _Irradiance Volume_.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.